# Detect Browser Vs. Software PHP

Tags: java, php, url, browser

So. I'm accessing a PHP page and reading some data from it using a Java URL() object. I was wondering if someone could show me how, using PHP, to check if the person viewing the page is accessing it from the Java application, or from a real web browser (I don't want them to see the data if they're using a web browser).

My current Java Code is:

```
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://www.mysite.com/myurl.php");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        while(s.hasNext()){
            String auths = s.next();
            String real = "test";
            if(auths.equalsIgnoreCase(real)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
```

And my PHP file at "http://www.mysite.com/myurl.php" has this code:

```
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

Thing is, I only want the PHP file to output the "test", if it's being accessed from the Java application. Can anyone help me out?.. Thanks

Comment: There's not an authoritative way to do this, AFAIK.  Web browsers *usually* send an indication in their user-agent string, but this can easily be faked since it's just a HTTP header. I guess what I'm trying to say is that the Java code you have written probably won't "look" like it came from a web browser, but it could easily be modified to do so by adding the appropriate headers, etc. to the request.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no foolproof solution for what you're trying to do.**

Having this said you can use [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) or `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to read the `user-agent` request header.